# Different shadow size of similar views on lollipop

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

My layout contains material style buttons, which up when clicked. On lollipop buttons shadow at the bottom of screen larger than button shadow at the top of screen. Button shadow at the bottom of screen looks ugly. Can I disable this render effect for buttons?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:text="BUTTON" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@xml/state_list_animator" />

    <Button
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:text="BUTTON" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@xml/state_list_animator" />

</FrameLayout>
```

button_blue (drawable-v21):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@color/button_blue_pressed">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/button_blue" />
        <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="8dp"
            android:right="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</ripple>
```

state_list_animator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:state_pressed="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="100"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="6"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="0"
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="2"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
<!-- base state -->
<item android:state_enabled="true">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="100"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:startDelay="20"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="0"
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="2"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
</item>
</selector>
```

result:
[image: result]

google news app with this effect: 
[image: google news app with this effect]

Comment: its not button its cardview that's why its look diffrent

Comment: the problem applies any view with shadow, like button, or cardView, or other views

Comment: look to latest screenshot (with google news app):cardView shadow on top of screen is smaller than cardView shadow on bottom of screen (selected red rectangles)

Comment: This is because of the position of the light source. Views at the bottom will always have bigger shadow compared to ones at the top of the screen. Apparently this is not a bug but a feature of material design implementation.